# Creating UI for Mongo DB in Meteor App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I wish to create a UI for Meteor Application which is able to extract and display information from the MongoDb on a separate machine. Currently I am going through 
[houston](https://github.com/gterrono/houston) and trying to customize it. Am I going in the right direction or are there other ways to do the same? I am new to meteor, any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: yes you are going in the right direction. i wanted to do something like this my self. and i was looking at https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin

Comment: So are you able to customize it? I also saw this and orion